# A rhyming riddle which rhymes

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> This is a type of puzzle,
> Where you don't need any muscle,
> Or you don't need to strain,
> Just use your brain.

> But if you still strain,
> You will do no gain.
> That was Hint 1,
> Hope you find it fun.

> Use too anger neither,
> It wont help you either.
> How was Hint 2?
> For more hints, see Panda's 2 Kung Fu.

> You don't need also tension,
> Just use your sensation.
> That was hint 3,
> Close your eyes, and just don't see.

> Anger, tension and strain, all the small bits.
> Are all opposite of this.
> And do you know what is this?
> Well, the answer to the quiz!

> And if you want this puzzle solved,
> Get yourself a bit involved.
> Just do what I mentioned,
> And be no more questioned.

Comment: Sorry, just realised, the brain is a muscle.

Comment: What do we need to find, a word that describes each stanza?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes. A word that passes to each paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the answer is :-

> Peace

> This is a type of puzzle,
> Where you don't need any muscle,
> Or you don't need to strain,
> Just use your brain.

> Of course this is a puzzle, and you don't need to any sort of physical work to feel peaceful. You don't need to strain either, and I guess the OP is suggesting to use the brain to get it in peace and not do any mind work, as it tires the brain. Not sure about this though.

> But if you still strain,
> You will do no gain.
> That was Hint 1,
> Hope you find it fun.

> Straining will have no gain as that will not make you get you peace in either way.

> Use too anger neither,
> It wont help you either.
> How was Hint 2?
> For more hints, see Panda's 2 Kung Fu.

> Being angry will also not make you get peace. And for the 4th line I suppose the OP just wanted to add another line to complete the rhythm of the stanza, as this does not really explain the answer, but I guess you can do Kung Fu well if you are especially calm and peaceful.

> You don't need also tension,
> Just use your sensation.
> That was hint 3,
> Close your eyes, and just don't see.

> You won't be getting peace if you get tensed, to feel calm you need to sense it. People get peace and feel relieved only when the close their eyes and don't see.

> Anger, tension and strain, all the small bits.
> Are all opposite of this.
> And do you know what is this?
> Well, the answer to the quiz!

> Anger, tension and strain are of course, opposite of getting peace. And I guess this is the answer of the quiz too.

> And if you want this puzzle solved,
> Get yourself a bit involved.
> Just do what I mentioned,
> And be no more questioned.

> I got myself a bit involved, and did what you mentioned. You told me not to strain, not to feel angry and get tensed, and to close my eyes. I then, felt the peace.

Comment: Correct. You realized mostly everything, except in the second clue I tried to mention The film Kung Fu panda 2, where the main topic is peace. Great answer, though.